# Error updating package data

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Hi guys I hope you can help as I've just done a fresh install of the latest bullseye raspbian and cannot manage to do an update or Recommended softwareinstall I recieve the following message:

```
Error updating package data - 
E:http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian 
bullseye InRelease is not (yet) available 
(Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org')
```

Comment: You have a DNS error.

Comment: The problem is in the last line of the error.  Can you reach any site by name (not IP number) when this happens?  If not but IP addresses work, DNS is busted/unavailable (as Dougie observes).

Comment: Im sorry guys I sorted it out, it was my internet connection that was very low I rebooted my router and all is good, thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

When I have gotten this error it is because my timedate is off far enough the RaspberryPi server SSL is not allowing the update.  Check you timedatectl and see what that you are on the correct date and within a few minutes of the correct time, as well as the correct timezone.